# Send my congratulation to mr

Tags: english-to-german

Today is international women day and I want to send my congratulations to wife of my colleague

Did I write correctly?

Überbringen  Frau Schneider Glückwünsche von mir

Comment: What do you want to congratulate her for? For being a woman and thus possibly putting up with less pay for the same work?

Comment: International Womens' Day is a national holiday in some Eastern European Countries. It does not have the same importance in German speaking countries.

Comment: @xyldke: Holidays are regulated on state level in Germany; Berlin is the only state, which already has adopted it. I guess its significance is rising.

Answer (score 1):

I'm slightly confused that you address her as *Frau Schneider*. If you don't know her (well) it might seem a bit weird for you to send your wishes.

If you do consider yourself being friends, then you can use one of the following

> Richte ihr einen frohen Frauentag von mir aus.

> Und sag ihr, ich wünsche ihr alles Gute zum Frauentag.

These all address your colleague as "du". You should know and address them on a first name basis, otherwise you might offend them. However, if you're not (yet) on a first name basis, then again I don't think these wishes are appropriate.

Comment: Indeed +1. I think one might send regards in some circumstance, but otherwise... weired or creepy.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the circumstances.

1. How do you address your college ("Du" or "Sie")?
2. Do you know his wife personally?

If you do not know his wife, you should not send congratulations.

In German it is unusual to refer to the wife of Mr. Schneider as Mrs. Schneider in the given context.

I suggest to write

- Richte Deiner Frau (or Richten Sie Ihrer Frau) bitte meine Glückwünsche zum Frauentag aus.

If you want to be more formal, you can also use "Gattin" instead of "Frau".